# Java Connectivity

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I have a scenario, I have a module in eclipse where need to insert a data into my sql. Here the connection is established successfully and code to insert data also executed successfully without any error in log. But data need to insert into my sql is not inserted. Can anyone clarify me.

Comment: Post the relevant code. We cannot read your mind.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Did you use transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you paste your code snippet so that it will be easy to answer your question.
Still just on guess, after `statement.executeUpdate()` method are you calling method `connection.commit()` ?
if not then add it and try again.